# node red setInterval return same value

Tags: javascript, mqtt, setinterval, node-red

my problem is that I have a function node that read the input 0 or 1 from PIR sensor every 2 seconds. I want my function node to keep output 1 for 10 seconds once a 1 is read from the sensor.

```
var newMsg;

if (msg.payload === 1 ){
    newMsg = {payload:0};
    setInterval(returnMsg, 10000);
}

else{
    newMsg = {payload:1};
}

return newMsg;



function returnMsg(){
    return newMsg;
}
```

I try to use setInterval that but it doesn't work.

edit:

Thank you all so much for replying!

so to be specific:

[flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mi8v.png)

and the gauge will be like this:

[gauge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tLuw.png)

what I am trying to do is that once a motion is detected by the PIR sensor, the gauge will show at 0 for like 10s. but now the gauge is keep changing once the reading from sensor change.

Comment: Where is the code that makes this run every 2 seconds?

Comment: Do you think the code is going to keep updating the if/else? Not sure what you expect the returnMsg to return from setInterval.... I think you need to share what you are actually trying to accomplish since what you are doing seems wrong.

Comment: @putvande it is not actually 2s, I am sorry I was trying to simplify my problem. it actually keep reading from the sensor.

Comment: @epascarello  thank you for your reply. I have edited my question. I hope it is more specific now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to address your requirement is to use a switch node as a gate. This gate will be initially opened allowing the flow of messages. When the payload is "1", indicating that the PIR is triggered, the code inside the function node will close the gate by changing a flow context variable that controls the switch node. At the same time, the code in the function node will configure a callback function to reopen the gate within 10 seconds.

Code inside the function:

```
if (msg.payload === 1) {
    closeGate();
}


function closeGate() {
        flow.set("gateopen", false); //close gate
        setTimeout(openGate, 10000); // reopen gate within 10 seconds
}


function openGate() {
    flow.set("gateopen", true);
}

flow.get("gateopen") ? node.status({fill:"green",shape:"ring",text:"Opened"}) :
                       node.status({fill:"red",shape:"ring",text:"Closed"});

return msg;
```

Flow :

```
[{"id":"8696aea0.42f8f","type":"tab","label":"Flow 3","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"e3f585c9.421cb8","type":"inject","z":"8696aea0.42f8f","name":"","topic":"","payload":"0","payloadType":"num","repeat":"2","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":"0.5","x":190,"y":200,"wires":[["be4bd9b8.de4d78"]]},{"id":"be4bd9b8.de4d78","type":"switch","z":"8696aea0.42f8f","name":"","property":"gateopen","propertyType":"flow","rules":[{"t":"true"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":1,"x":370,"y":220,"wires":[["23cd0407.7efcec"]]},{"id":"63b4ec7c.b18904","type":"inject","z":"8696aea0.42f8f","name":"","topic":"","payload":"1","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":190,"y":240,"wires":[["be4bd9b8.de4d78"]]},{"id":"db6c9c0d.4c21b","type":"debug","z":"8696aea0.42f8f","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":true,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","x":670,"y":220,"wires":[]},{"id":"fbf0ec86.55906","type":"inject","z":"8696aea0.42f8f","name":"Open gate","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":"0.5","x":190,"y":120,"wires":[["2325a5f7.0d1d1a"]]},{"id":"23cd0407.7efcec","type":"function","z":"8696aea0.42f8f","name":"Gate","func":"if (msg.payload === 1) {\n    closeGate();\n}\n\n\nfunction closeGate() {\n        flow.set(\"gateopen\", false); //close gate\n        setTimeout(openGate, 10000); // reopen gate within 10 seconds\n}\n\n\nfunction openGate() {\n    flow.set(\"gateopen\", true);\n}\n\nflow.get(\"gateopen\") ? node.status({fill:\"green\",shape:\"ring\",text:\"Opened\"}) :\n                       node.status({fill:\"red\",shape:\"ring\",text:\"Closed\"});\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":510,"y":220,"wires":[["db6c9c0d.4c21b"]]},{"id":"2325a5f7.0d1d1a","type":"change","z":"8696aea0.42f8f","name":"Open gate","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"gateopen","pt":"flow","to":"true","tot":"bool"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":350,"y":120,"wires":[[]]}]
```

[image]

Below an alternative flow for extending the timer if a new PIR event takes place:

```
[{"id":"585ba08b.3667e","type":"tab","label":"Flow 3","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"4cb35501.7c04fc","type":"inject","z":"585ba08b.3667e","name":"","topic":"","payload":"0","payloadType":"num","repeat":"2","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":"0.5","x":190,"y":200,"wires":[["87ab9f12.fd8ad"]]},{"id":"e1699672.cb5788","type":"switch","z":"585ba08b.3667e","name":"","property":"gateopen","propertyType":"flow","rules":[{"t":"true"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":1,"x":590,"y":200,"wires":[["c40dbf1f.79ef4"]]},{"id":"aafaf20e.95d46","type":"inject","z":"585ba08b.3667e","name":"","topic":"","payload":"1","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":190,"y":240,"wires":[["87ab9f12.fd8ad"]]},{"id":"c40dbf1f.79ef4","type":"debug","z":"585ba08b.3667e","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":true,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","x":810,"y":200,"wires":[]},{"id":"5e76c261.a4f9ac","type":"inject","z":"585ba08b.3667e","name":"Open gate","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":"0.5","x":190,"y":120,"wires":[["b255cf40.af298"]]},{"id":"4c13bbad.850434","type":"function","z":"585ba08b.3667e","name":"Gate","func":"if (flow.get(\"gateopen\")) {\n    closeGate(); // gate is opened and will be closes it for 10 seconds\n} else {\n    extendGate(); // gate is already closed. The timer will reset and  new 10 second timeout will start\n}\n\n\nfunction closeGate() {\n        flow.set(\"gateopen\", false); //close gate\n        flow.set(\"gateid\", setTimeout(openGate, 10000));\n}\n\n\nfunction openGate() {\n    flow.set(\"gateopen\", true);\n}\n\nfunction extendGate() {\n    clearTimeout(flow.get(\"gateid\"));\n    closeGate();\n}\n\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":590,"y":240,"wires":[["c40dbf1f.79ef4"]]},{"id":"b255cf40.af298","type":"change","z":"585ba08b.3667e","name":"Open gate","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"gateopen","pt":"flow","to":"true","tot":"bool"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":350,"y":120,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"87ab9f12.fd8ad","type":"switch","z":"585ba08b.3667e","name":"","property":"payload","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"eq","v":"0","vt":"num"},{"t":"eq","v":"1","vt":"num"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":2,"x":370,"y":220,"wires":[["e1699672.cb5788"],["4c13bbad.850434"]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: You are not clearing the timeout to extend the window if another 1 Congress in before 10 seconds is up

Comment: Indeed, good point @hardillb.  The flow was designed on the assumption that there is no requirement to extend the window (of course when it is already active). If this is a requirement (that makes sense but was not explicitly stated in the OP)  then it is necessary to refactor the flow. A new "1" will never reach the function gate when the timeout is active. The way the flow works blocks the payload (0 or 1 or whatever) in the previous node.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I imported your flow and didn't change anything, but it doesn't work properly. No output no matter which node is injected and the node status is not shown.

Comment: @Gary Lin, I wonder if you have a very old version of Node-RED that does not support persistent context. Could you post the Node-RED version you are using?

Comment: @AIOTMAKER I am using 0.19.6

Comment: @Gary Lin, I renamed the flow variable by mistake before posting the flow. It is fixed now.  I apologize. It should work now if you import the flow again or more quickly if you fix the variable name in the switch node  to `flow.gateopen`

Comment: @AIOTMAKER do you mind if I ask you how I can extend the window? I am sorry I didn't stated in the OP.  I tried to add another function node before the switch node to clearTimeout once `flow.get("gateopen") ===false && msg.payload === 1)`, then `clearTimeout(flow.t1);`. But this doesn't work and I am not sure if I am doing it right.

Comment: @Gat Lin, I will edit the reply to add an alternative Node-RED flow that extends the timer. However, you will notice that there is a kind of quirk with this solution. NodeRED will show a "circular reference" warning in the debug panel. This happens because Node.JS returns a handler for the setTImeout that is an object and this object has a circular reference (should not be serialized). I don't know if there is a perfect solution to this issue. I will do some additional search but most likely will end up opening a question in StackOverflow or Node-RED forum.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if less than 10 seconds have passed since last `1` received:

this line should be outside your function that reads sensor value

```
var last = new Date(2000, 1, 1,  1, 1);
```

and then in your function:

```
if (msg.payload === 1 ){
    last = new Date();
}

return (new Date() - last)<10000?1:0;
```

Comment: That won't work as the last variable will be reset every time a new message arrives. The function node's scope is reset for every incoming message.

Comment: @hardillb it won't reset (it is not inside function that reads the sensor) and it will be set if read value is 1

Comment: thank you so much  for your reply. I try your code but it is still not working. I edit my question to make it more specific.

Comment: Yes it will, that whole block of code is in a Node-RED function node, the whole scope gets thrown out on every invitation (every 2 seconds when the pir gets polled) this is not a normal JavaScript environment

Comment: @hardillb I am very new to this. do you have any idea what I should do?